# Spark streaming: Scheduling time more than processing time

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql, azure-eventhub

We have a streaming job in Spark 2.1 reading from Azure EventHub (spark-streaming-eventhubs_2.11:2.0.5) with a batch interval of 5s. 
We are seeing avg processing time of around 3s . However we see the time interval between the batches is around 20s. The below log shows the end/begin of the batches. This is causing the overall processing to fall behind. There are no errors in the processing.

Any ideas what could be causing such delays in scheduling? YarnUI is showing the avg delay as 0s. Not sure why the time interval between the batches is delayed.

```
17/07/21 23:38:06 WARN root: !!!!!!!!    Posted Batch count : 420  Time : 224800
17/07/21 23:38:06 WARN root: ----End of batch--------
17/07/21 23:38:25 WARN root: ----Start of batch--------
17/07/21 23:38:26 WARN root: df.rdd.partitions.size=50
17/07/21 23:38:26 WARN root: blockData.rdd.partitions.size=50
17/07/21 23:38:26 WARN root: finalData.rdd.partitions.size=50

[Stage 2590:=================================================>     (9 + 1) / 10]

17/07/21 23:38:28 WARN root: !!!!!!!!    Posted Batch count : 256  Time : 224805
17/07/21 23:38:28 WARN root: ----End of batch--------
17/07/21 23:38:47 WARN root: ----Start of batch--------
17/07/21 23:38:48 WARN root: df.rdd.partitions.size=50
17/07/21 23:38:48 WARN root: blockData.rdd.partitions.size=50
17/07/21 23:38:48 WARN root: finalData.rdd.partitions.size=50
```

The simplified repro code is:

```
 eventHubDStream.foreachRDD((rdd: RDD[Array[Byte]], time: Time) => {

val strRDD = rdd.map(w => new String(w))
val df = spark.read.schema(schema).json(rdd)
df.createOrReplaceTempView("table")
val filteredDf = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM table WHERE EventName='Start')
val count = filteredDf.count()

}
```

Comment: Can you provide the code that you have written for processing stream?

Comment: without looking at the code is hard to know indeed. You can click on the Streaming UI and see what job is taking so much time and drill down from there.

Comment: Updated the original post with the code snippet. Its pretty straightforward code that is doing a simple filtering.